# Multiple sorts in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [note] => test
        [year] => 2011
        [type] => football
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [note] => test1
        [year] => 2010
        [type] => basket
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [note] => test2
        [year] => 2012
        [type] => football
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [note] => test3
        [year] => 2009
        [type] => basket
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [note] => test4
        [year] => 2010
        [type] => football
    )

)
```

And I would like to first sort it according another array by type:

For example: `$sort = array('football','basket');`

And afterwards by year.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Desired output should be:

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [note] => test2
        [year] => 2012
        [type] => football
    )
[0] => Array
    (
        [note] => test
        [year] => 2011
        [type] => football
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [note] => test4
        [year] => 2010
        [type] => football
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [note] => test1
        [year] => 2010
        [type] => basket
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [note] => test3
        [year] => 2009
        [type] => basket
    )

)
```

I do not mind if we reset the index values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). Assuming your array is `$arr`:

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$row) {
    $type[$key] = $row['type'];
    $year[$key] = $row['year'];
}
array_multisort($type, SORT_ASC, $year, SORT_ASC, $arr);
```

To use an addictional array specifying type order, you could do:

```
$sortBy = array('football','basket');
foreach($arr as $key=>$row) {
    $type[$key] = array_search($row['type'],$sortBy);
    $year[$key] = $row['year'];
}
array_multisort($type, SORT_ASC, $year, SORT_ASC, $arr);
```

Example link:

http://codepad.org/qhZCpbZE

Comment: Thanks mate it seems to work. But how can I include the $sortBy array as well?

Comment: Thanks mate it seems to work as expected. a quick question. Why do we still use `$type, SORT_ASC` if we are sorting by another array?

Comment: @salamis We sort by `$type` array in both cases. In the first case it's an array of type names (strings). In second case it's an array of type positions in `$sortBy` (integers or false if type is not present in `$sortBy`).

Comment: Thanks mate! Thanks a lot for the descriptive answer.

Comment: Here is an example link for everyone interested in the future! http://codepad.org/qhZCpbZE

Answer (score 4):

Requires a version of PHP that supports closures when run as-is

Your secondary array can be defined outside of the sort itself. If you can't support closures, then this can be put directly into the sort routine.

```
$sortBy = array('football', 'basket');
```

Sort routine.

Sorts by year if types are the same, and sorts by the types in your `$sortBy` array otherwise.

```
usort($a, function($a, $b) use ($sortBy) {
    if ($a['type'] == $b['type']) {
        return ($b['year'] - $a['year']);
    }
    $typeOrder = array_flip($sortBy);
    return $typeOrder[$a['type']] - $typeOrder[$b['type']];
});
```

Comment: How can I use this? I tried http://codepad.org/HCodcfgl but it doesn't seem to work mate. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @salamis Codepad is PHP 5.2, which is 6 years old, and does not support closures. What version of PHP do **you** use? (You can use [Viper 7's codepad too](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MpTYaB))

Answer (score 1):

Use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
function byType($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['type'] == $b['type']) {
        return 0;
    }

    foreach(array('football','basket') as $type) {
        if ($a['type']=$type) return -1;
        if ($b['type']=$type) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


function byYear($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['year'] == $b['year']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['year'] < $b['year']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array,"byType");
usort($array,"byYear");
```

Comment: It is not working mate. First of all because I cannot use another array to sort by type. And secondly when the second usort is performed everything get mixed again. Please check: http://codepad.org/PO3CvGsu and the desired result. I would like the sort by year to happen only if the type is the same.

Comment: @Adnan It does not work, change the array, it currently works by "luck"

Comment: That does not do what the OP asked for.